# Dimetric Screen to World coordinates

Tags: 3d, matrix, isometric, projection

I've got a successful projection of world coordinates to the screen, but when I try to generate a ray for screen coordinates to the world, it always generates a fixed point which is invalid.

I started with the PixelBimetric projection from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6668834/true-isometric-projection-with-html5-canvas):
\begin{bmatrix}1&0.5&0.5&0\\-1&0.5&0.5&0\\0&-1&1&0\\a&b&0&1\end{bmatrix}

I've multiplied that by the Orthagraphic matrix from [here](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/168899/3d-isometric-projection-matrix). But since I'm using the unit box -1,1. It's equivalent to the identity matrix. I've then set `a` & `b` to the `x`&`y` offsets to centre the viewpoint and scale the whole matrix by a factor `s` to fit the screen.

This works for creating a Dimetric projection of the world space to the screen by doing:

$$\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\\z\\1\end{bmatrix}*M$$

When I try to go from screen to world space I do the following to get the two ends of a ray in world space:
$$\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\\0\\1\end{bmatrix}*inv(M)\quad\&\quad  \begin{bmatrix}x\\y\\1\\1\end{bmatrix}*inv(M)$$

But they're almost identical.

I'm assuming there's atleast one fundamental thing I'm doing wrong/missing? If it matters, I'm working with MathJs. Code:

```
import { P2, P3, P3Array, Point2D, Point3D, toNumber } from "types";
import { GRID_SIZE, SCREEN_OFFSET } from "./constants";
import { Matrix, add, inv, matrix, multiply } from "mathjs";

const r = 1
const l = -1
const t = 1
const b = -1
const f = -1
const n = 1

const ogProjectionMatrix = multiply(
  matrix([
    [1 , 0.5, 0.5, 0],
    [-1, 0.5, 0.5, 0],
    [0 , -1 , 1  , 0],
    [0 , 0  , 0  , 1]
  ]),
  matrix([
    [2/(r-l), 0      , 0      , -(r+l)/(r-l)],
    [0      , 2/(t-b), 0      , -(t+b)/(t-b)],
    [0      , 0      , 2/(f-n), -(f+n)/(f-n)],
    [0      , 0      , 0      , 1           ]
  ])
)

const projectionMatrix = () => multiply(
  add(
    ogProjectionMatrix,
    [
      [0, 0, 0, 0],
      [0, 0, 0, 0],
      [0, 0, 0, 0],
      [SCREEN_OFFSET.x/2, SCREEN_OFFSET.y/2, 0, 0]
    ]
  ),
  GRID_SIZE) as Matrix

const projectionObject = {
  matrix: projectionMatrix(),
  inverse: inv(projectionMatrix()),
  project(p: Point3D): Point2D {
    return P2(...multiply([...P3Array(p), 1], this.matrix).toArray())
  },
  zIndex(p: Point3D): number {
    return toNumber(multiply([...P3Array(p), 1], this.matrix).toArray()[2])
  },
  inverseProject(p: Point2D): [Point3D, Point3D] {
    return [
      P3(...multiply([p.x, p.y, 0, 1], this.inverse).toArray()),
      P3(...multiply([p.x, p.y, 1, 1], this.inverse).toArray())
    ]
  }
}

export default projectionObject
```

Comment: Turns first mistake was ordering my multiplication of matrices wrong when verifying the inverse